# typescript Cannot add headers to a fetch api using react-native

Tags: json, typescript, react-native, fetch-api

I am using Fetch API from react-native and I am using typescript. 
My code looks like this:

```
let responseLogin = await fetch('http://url_example', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: requestBody
    });
```

But I get the following error where the header is:

```
 Argument of type '{ method: string; headers: { 'Content-Type': string; }; body: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type '{ 'Content-Type': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers | string[][]'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Content-Type'' does not exist in type 'Headers | string[][]'.
```

I have also tried to create a custom header but without any luck:

```
    let requestHeaders = new Headers();
        requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        // I have also tried adding this at the end but no luck 
        // requestHeaders.get('Content-Type');
```

How could I add a header to this? Because I cannot find any way to make this happen and I don't know what is the problem. If I test these in postman, I get a 200 response, here I get a 401 response.
I have also tried this library just to add custom headers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-headers

I use:
Visual studio code 1.81.1
"react-native": "0.50.0",
"typescript": "2.6.1"

Comment: does it require any credentials to be send ?

Comment: have you tried using `headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }` in the `fetch` api

Comment: you may need to add `credentials: 'include' ` in the fetch request if you are sending credentials

Comment: @Niladri I am sending a username and a password. Yes I have tried with your second suggestion and it said the same thing. I have not tried with credentials, I will trie and come back with an answer.

Comment: @Niladri I have tried with credentials: 'include', it is still not working.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Can you try typing it as `HeadersInit`?

```
const requestHeaders: HeadersInit = new Headers();
requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

const responseLogin = await fetch('URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: requestHeaders,
  body: requestBody
});
```

If not, can you show the error you are getting when you are initiating it with the Headers() constructor, you showed in the question?

Comment: Same problem here, here's the error I get when typing it as `HeadersInit`:  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers | string[][] | { [key: string]: string; } | undefined'.  (How is type `Headers` not assignable to type `Headers | ...`?)

Comment: What is the typescript version you are using in your package.json?

Comment: It’s `^3.2.2`, added automatically by the Firebase cloud functions setup

Comment: Oke, that isn't the issue then. But you are not required to give a type, so you can also only do 
```const requestHeaders = new Headers();```

Comment: The type in the `HeadersInit` contains other types, not only `Headers`, so you actually should _not_ put the type there.

Answer (score 7):

What TypeScript libraries are you including with your build? It looks like your definition for the `headers` property is wrong. In TypeScript 2.6.2, the `headers` property is of type `HeadersInit`, which is defined as:
`type HeadersInit = Headers | string[][] | { [key: string]: string };`

Comment: I have tried to add the headers like this: headers: [['Content-Type'] , ['application/json']]. Still it returns a status of 401.

Comment: I have also tried this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-headers

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by importing `Headers` like this:

```js
import fetch, { Headers } from 'node-fetch';
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer has the caveat that it doesn't handle the scenario where you encapsulate `fetch` into a function of your own that receives the same arguments as `fetch` and sets defaults to the `headers` property. For example:

```
async function myFetch(input: RequestInfo, init: RequestInit) {
  // set some headers here
  const res = await fetch(input, init)
  // return something from the response here, handle errors
}
```

The problem with the resolved answer is that `RequestInit.headers` is of type `HeadersInit` whose definition is:

```
type HeadersInit = string[][] | Record<string, string> | Headers;
```

When I try to set defaults for `headers` but still use headers passed by the calling function, I run into issues because of these possible multiple types that I need to deal with.

What I resolved out of complete exasperation is to define my own `RequestInit` type where `headers` is only `Record<string, string>`. I don't care about the other types, an object of string key/values IS fine.

```
export interface MyRequestInit extends Omit<RequestInit, 'headers'> {
  headers?: Record<string, string>;
}

export async function fetchJson<JSON = unknown>(
  input: RequestInfo,
  init: MyRequestInit = {},
) {
  // set my own default headers here
  const res = await fetch(input, init)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but the accepted answer would not work in my case because headers might have been already initialized. So

```
    if (!requestInit.headers) {
      requestInit.headers = new Headers()
    }

    requestInit.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    // *TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'HeadersInit'. Property 'set' does not exist on type 'string[][]'*
```

Produces compilation error because, like others pointed out, HeadersInit is defined as `type HeadersInit = string[][] | Record<string, string> | Headers;`

**FIX: use constructor with param**

```
requestInit.headers = new Headers(requestInit.headers)
requestInit.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem like this:

```
let requestHeaders: any = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
let responseLogin = await fetch('URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: requestHeaders,
  body: requestBody
});
```

All that I had to do was to ignore that error message because JS interprets the syntax correctly, only typescript doesn't and I did that by creating a variable in which I stored those two strings.

Comment: Or you can also try `let requestHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } as Headers;` if you have strict any.

Comment: Not sure adding `any` is a good way to solve a typescript problem.

Comment: I think @kutomer suggested using the [noImplicitAny](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) option to the TypeScript transpiler so you would get an error if TS couldn't infer something other than `any` as your object type. Not explicitly declaring a type of `any`.